# Prove $X_g \subseteq X_f $ if and only if $g\in \sqrt{(f)}$. My proof is ok?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, $f,g\in R$. Prove $X_g \subseteq X_f $ if and only if $g\in \sqrt{(f)}$.

Ref Lemma 2.10, page 53, *Algebraic Geometry 1. From Algebraic Varieties to Schemes* - Kenji Ueno

**Context**: $X=Spec(R)$

$(f)$ is the ideal generated by $f$

$X_g =(Spec(R))_g=D(g)=\lbrace P\in Spec(R) | g\notin P\rbrace$

$\sqrt{(f)}=\lbrace h\in R|$ exist $m\in \mathbb{Z}^+,h^m\in (f)\rbrace $

**My solution:** the book proof is different

$\Rightarrow )$ assume that $X_g \subseteq X_f $ by contradiction assume that $g\notin \sqrt{(f)}$ then for all $m\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $g^m\notin (f)$ by def ideal in $(f)$, $g\notin (f)$ thus $(f)\in X_g\subseteq X_f$, then $f\notin (f) $ $(\rightarrow \leftarrow)$

$\Leftarrow )$ Assume that $g\in \sqrt{(f)}$. Let $P\in X_g$, so $g\notin P$ since $g\in \sqrt{(f)}$ exist $m\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $g^m\in (f)$. i.e. $g^m=fk$ for some $k\in R$. since $g\notin P$

if $g^m\in P$ then $gg^{m-1}\in P$ but $P$ is prime ideal, $g^{m-1}\in P$ then $gg^{m-2}\in P$ and for the same reason $g^{m-2}\in P$ doing $m-1$ times this, we conclude that $gg^{m-(m-1)}\in P$ thus $g\in P$ $(\rightarrow \leftarrow)$

thus $g^m\notin P$, $g^m=fk\notin P$, then $f\notin P$ because P is ideal. we conclude that $P\in 
 X_f$

Comment: Your proof of $\impliedby$ is correct, but your proof of $\implies$ is not. You implicitly assume that the principal ideal $fR$ is prime when you write $(f) \in X_{g}$, but this may not be the case.

Comment: Thank you. You are right!

Answer (score 2):

Recall $\sqrt{(f)}=\bigcap_{\mathfrak p\supset (f)}\mathfrak p$
the intersection over all prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ of $R$ containing $f$.

Now $g\notin \sqrt{(f)}$ implies there is a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ containing $(f)$ such that $g\notin \mathfrak p$. Thus $\mathfrak p\in X_g$. But $X_g\subseteq X_f$ implies $\mathfrak p\in X_f$, that is a contradiction as $f\in \mathfrak p$.